# Design an API for a web service without "selling the farm"?

Tags: api

I'm going to try to phrase this as a generic question.

A company runs a website that has a lot of valuable information on it. This information is queried from an internal private database. So technically, the information in the database is the valuable part.

If this company wished to develop an API that developers could use to access their database of valuable & useful information, what approach should the company take?

It's important to give developers what they need. But it is also important to keep competing websites from essentially using the API to steal everything and essentially steal all traffic from the company's website.

Is there was some way the API could be used in a way that drives traffic back to the original company's website somehow? Something that gives users a reason to keep going there.

This is a design consideration that my company is struggling with that I can imagine other web-based services have come across before.

Answer (score 3):

1. Institute API keys - don't make it public. Maybe make the signup process more complex than "anyone with an e-mail address".
2. Rate limit the API based on keys. If you're running more than X requests a minute, you're likely mining the database.
3. Don't provide a "fetch everything" API. Make the users know something to get information on it. Don't reveal what you know.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a lot of companies giving out API keys and stating a TOS that all developers must adhere to. For example, any page that uses data from the API must include your logo and a link back to your website. If any developer is found breaking the rules, the API key can be cancelled and your data is safe again.

Answer (score 0):

Who is meant to use the API?

A good general method of solving this problem is to limit access to the data to end users (rather than allow applications or developers at it). Provide applications and users with identification, each, and make sure that to access a subset of the data, a combination of both user and application key is required.

Following this pattern, each user will have access to a very limited subset of the data (presumably, the data that they require for their own specific use), and you can put measures in place to enforce this. Any attempts at data-mining will become obvious.

This type of approach meshes well with capability-type security models on the server side.